# How to: datagrid cell size changed when windows size changed

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Firstly, my window is set to 900px height and 600px width. It contains a datagrid with 4 columns. I've created a template for cells, the widths are, say, 100px. Now when I change the window sizes, I want cells' width to grow proportionally to size of windows. I tried to add datagrid sizes change event but it didn't work.

How can I do this? Thanks!

**Update**: one more question: Have any way to make the sizes of a cell is the same whether they're empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

In grid definition

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
          <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" MinWidth="70" />             
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> 
       ...
```

MinWidth :  Gets or sets the minimum width constraint of the element.

Comment: I tried and this way still didn't work. The sizes of datagrid did change but cells' sizes didn't. there's another column added to the datagrid when datagrid is maximized.

Comment: Could you please put some XAML code of your grid?  maybe it does not update the size of controls you have in the cells? Try to set HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" for controls inside cells...